# What is the difference between .deb and .app 

Tags: iphone, deb

I have come across some of the jailbroken applications which use package files named with the extension .deb . So how it is related to iPhone and how it is different from .app .

Answer (score 2):

.deb is a package management format used on Debian-based Linux distributions. Ubuntu, for example, uses .deb files to manage installation of software.

.deb files are not specific to Debian though and can be used on any compatible *nix platform. fink for Mac OS X is .deb-based, I believe.

So, to answer one half of your question, .deb files are used to install certain jailbroken applications into your iPhone.

.app files, on the other hand, are Apple's format for assembled applications. They contain everything you need to run them.

The main difference is that with .app files, that is the actual application itself. With .deb files, it contains the instructions for how to install the application.

Hope this helps.

Comment: .deb is used by Cydia, which is probably where the OP has seen this.

Answer (score 0):

[.deb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deb_%28file_format%29)

Comment: While the link is technically correct, it does not describe how this differs from .app.